# @mock annotation with custom Answer class in Mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I'm using Mockito with Spring Framework in my project.

I have a test case like this:

```
class SomeTest {
    @Mock
    SomeDao dao; 

    @InjectMock
    TestTarget target;

    class MyAnswer implements Answer {
       //some method here
    }
}
```

I want define a custom Answer class `MyAnswer` for `dao`.

Without an annotation, I could use `Mockito.mock(Dao.class, new MyAnswer())` to force my mock object using MyAnswer. But I found with the `@Mock` annotation, they only accept parameters inside of `enum Answers` like `Answers.RETURNS_DEFAULT` or `Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS`.

Could I force the `dao` working with `MyAnswer` with `@Mock` annotation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not—you'll have to use `Mockito.mock` for this. There's currently no way to specify an Answer you've written through @Mock.

The reason has little to do with Mockito and everything to do with Java's annotations spec:

> Parameters may only be typed as a primitive, String, Class, enum, annotation, or an array of any of these. (Jason Hunter, ["Making the Most of Java's Metadata, Part 2: Custom Annotations"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/hunter-meta-2-098036.html))

and in the [Java Language Specification §9.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1):

> The return type of a method declared in an annotation type must be one of the following, or a compile-time error occurs:
>
> - A primitive type
> - String
> - Class or an invocation of Class (§4.5)
> - An enum type
> - An annotation type
> - An array type whose component type is one of the preceding types (§10.1).

Because the annotation type elements must be effectively VM-wide constants (including enum values but excluding arbitrary instances), there's no way to put an answer instance you create. Theoretically, Mockito could let you specify a named Answer *subclass*, but then Mockito would also be responsible for instantiating it, which is not always possible and which would cause runtime failures. If the feature is important to you anyway, you may consider making a [feature request](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It exactly help me understand the annotation logic in Java :)